# Jquery conflicts between jquery.js and jquery-1.9.0.js

Tags: jquery

I have two jquery one for responsive navigation and other for banner. But both are not working same time. I think there is jquery conflicts. when i comment  **jquery.js** for banner then banner with **jquery-1.9.0.js** is working well. Will any one please help me to fix this. I am going to give you the link of my page.[here is the link](http://dipannita.me/demo/) .  Its just a trial i am working. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Simple fix: use only one version of jquery

Answer (score 0):

See your console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on' "  from jquery.flexnav.min.js script.

That means that this script is coded for an newer version of jquery. So remove older version of jquery, use only the 1.9.1. This could give you other errors from other scripts but then use jquery migrate to upgrade them.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

delete old and use this version http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js Rmove old version like jquery-1.5.2.js and jquery-1.9.1.min.js